# Learn Python the Hard Way ex39

Tags: python, python-2.7

In exercise 39 of *Learn Python the Hard Way* (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html), the following functions are defined (`get_slot()` and `get()`):

```
def get_slot(aMap, key, default=None):
    """
    Returns the index, key, and value of a slot found in a bucket.
    Returns -1, key, and default (None if not set) when not found.
    """
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)

    for i, kv in enumerate(bucket):
        k, v = kv
        if key == k:
            return i, k, v
    return -1, key, default

def get(aMap, key, default=None):
    """Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default."""
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)
    return v
```

Why write `default=default` when calling `get_slot()` ?

It would seem to me that simply calling `get_slot()` with 'default' would be sufficient? -> `get_slot(aMap, key, default)`

Is the `default=default` something to do with named vs positional function parameters? (as are discussed here: http://pythoncentral.io/fun-with-python-function-parameters/)
or is the `default=default` done for a different reason entirely?

Comment: in this case it is the same, but it is generally good practice (safer) to also use the keyword argument names even when the position matches.

Comment: okay, so because 'default' is a named parameter, it is good practice to use the keyword argument 'default=' when calling the function? Have I understood correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` is a "key argument" for function `get_slot()` and its default value is None.
When you call `get_slot()` without specifying "default", it takes the value "None".
In the example above you're setting the key argument "default" to "default" which is the argument passed to the function "get", so it takes value `None`.

So in this particular case it doesn't change whether you call:

`get_slot(aMap, key)`

or

`get_slot(aMap, key, default = default)`

but if a value different from `None` was passed to the `get` function the `default` variable in your `get_slot` function would take a value different from `None`.

I hope this clears it a bit.

Comment: thanks for your answer, for some reason, the person that edited my question changed the code from 'None' to '1' (I've changed that back and added a link to the Learn Python the Hard Way example so that people can see the code in-situ).  Does this change your answer?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It actually changes the answer as in the end your `default` value will take the value `None`. The way the values are passed among the functions does not change, however the final result will. I'll update the answer!