# How can I add an assertion to only be valid for the first operation in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, assert

I am going through Learn Python the Hard Way and I couldn't find out how to do the fourth study drill of [exercise 39](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html):

"Read about Python's assert feature and then take the hashmap code and add assertions for each of the tests I've done instead of print. For example, you can assert that the first get operation returns "New York" instead of just printing that out."

The code in question is the same as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037145/learn-python-the-hard-way-ex39), but it didn't help me.

But it wasn't clear to me which function should assert, and he might want it in another function, like get_slot. Of these four functions, I'm not sure which he means for the reader to change and use to assert "New York" for the first hashmap.get(x, y) operation:

```
def get_bucket(aMap, key):
    """Given a key, find the bucket where it would go."""
    bucket_id = hash_key(aMap, key)
    return aMap[bucket_id]

def get_slot(aMap, key, default=None):
    """
    Returns the index, key, and value of a slot found in a bucket.
    Returns -1, key, and default (None if not set) when not found.
    """
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)

    for i, kv in enumerate(bucket):
        k, v = kv
        if key == k:
            return i, k, v

    return -1, key, default

def get(aMap, key, default=None):
    """Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default."""
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)
    return v

def set(aMap, key, value):
    """Sets the key to the value, replacing any existing value."""
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key)

    if i >= 0:
        # the key exists, replace it
        bucket[i] = (key, value)
    else:
        # the key does not, append to create it
        bucket.append((key, value))
```

A sample from the code that calls this method is:

```
# print out some cities
print '-' * 10
print "NY State has: %s" % hashmap.get(cities, 'NY')
print "OR State has: %s" % hashmap.get(cities, 'OR')
```

I read about assert and I was able to use it in the "get_slot" function to assert that key == k: but I couldn't figure out how to replace the if/else in the "set" function or how to assert that the first "get" operation is "New York" without getting errors for the other times "get" is called.

So is there a way to assert the first get operation returns "New York" without getting an error when get is called for other states?

Comment: Helping you is against the spirit of the book... Learn the hard way!

Comment: I know! But this is the first study drill so far I have been unable to figure out the hard way. I asked the author and haven't heard back, after two weeks.

Comment: Include code rather than images in your question

Comment: The assert should replace the print tag, not appear in the get_slot function.

Comment: @MarkPerryman I'll try that, but in the question, it says to put it in the hashmap code, not the exercise code where the print tag is, right? Or do you mean the print in the hashmap.py code?

Comment: @BenShapiro Post the section of code that's giving you problems.